Interaction has already been acknowledged with message component collectors
when i try my command, it's working for others (@ID) but for people who doesn't ping anyone, it doesn't work, just some error
First Error (no id, no ping) :
Interaction différée (navigation) poubelle_1308944865991721091
Erreur lors de la collecte de suppression : DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\BOT\²TEST\VersaceBots-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\BOT\²TEST\VersaceBots-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate (C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\BOT\²TEST\VersaceBots-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:192:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\BOT\²TEST\VersaceBots-main\commands\utilitaire\prevnames.js:128:17) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/interactions/1308944872585166898/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTMwODk0NDg3MjU4NTE2Njg5ODpURENXR2g5QldlS3ZyVkJBcmVQYldmYXlINmJDMkZEWkJjUTI0aU9HellIeXZiU0hUWFJOa2hSMWVEa0hiWWE0ZWdEU3dweWZZRFkwbUUwcVVwQ2FmWTJBOVM5UmhYaWRCWUpIb3BZTnBpdXFib1lKN0x2ZjJSbVNNN0RXeXdGWg/callback',
  code: 40060,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: { json: { type: 6 }, files: [] }
}

Second Error :
Interaction différée (corbeille) poubelle_1308944989975220326
Collecteur de suppression terminé.
Message supprimé par l'utilisateur mentionné.
Erreur lors de la collecte de suppression : Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at ButtonInteraction.reply (C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\BOT\²TEST\VersaceBots-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:94:46)
    at InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\BOT\²TEST\VersaceBots-main\commands\utilitaire\prevnames.js:143:43)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'
}

My code :
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {
    name: 'prevname',
    aliases: ["prevnames"],
    category: "utilitaire",
    usage: ["prevname", "prevname <@ID>", "prevnames", "prevnames <@ID>"],
    description: "Permet de voir les anciens noms d'utilisateurs d'un utilisateur",

    run: async (client, message, args, color, prefix, footer, commandName) => {
        let pass = false;
        let staff = client.staff;

        if (!staff.includes(message.author.id) && !client.config.buyers.includes(message.author.id) && client.db.get(`owner_${message.author.id}`) !== true) {
            pass = false;
        } else {
            pass = true;
        }

        if (pass === false) return message.channel.send(`Vous n'avez pas la permission d'utiliser cette commande.`);

        let membre = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
        if (!membre) {
            try {
                membre = await client.users.fetch(args[0]);
            } catch (e) {
                membre = message.author;
            }
        }

        const data = db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`prevname_${membre.id}`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data);
        const count = 15;
        let p0 = 0;
        let p1 = count;
        let page = 1;

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Liste des anciens pseudos de ${membre.username}`)
            .setColor(color)
            .setDescription(data.slice(p0, p1).map((m) => `**<t:${m.ID.split("_")[2]}>** - **${m.ID.split("_")[3]}**`).join("\n") || "Aucune donnée")
            .setFooter({ text: `${page}/${Math.ceil(data.length / count) === 0 ? 1 : Math.ceil(data.length / count)} ${client.footer}` });

        const btnPrev = new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId(`prev1_${message.id}`)
            .setLabel('◀')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
            .setDisabled(data.length <= count);

        const btnNext = new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId(`prev2_${message.id}`)
            .setLabel('▶')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
            .setDisabled(data.length <= count);

        const btnDelete = new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId(`poubelle_${message.id}`)
            .setLabel('️')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY');

        let row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(btnPrev, btnNext, btnDelete);

        if (data.length === 0) {
            row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(btnDelete);
        }

        const msg = await message.reply({
            allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false },
            components: [row],
            embeds: [embed],
        });

        const filterNavigation = (interaction) => interaction.isButton() && interaction.user.id === message.author.id;
        const filterDelete = (interaction) => interaction.isButton() && interaction.user.id === membre.id;

        let hasResponded = false; // Flag to track if interaction has been replied or deferred.

        const collectorNavigation = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({
            filter: filterNavigation,
            time: 30000,
        });

        const collectorDelete = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({
            filter: filterDelete,
            time: 30000,
        });

        // Collecteur de navigation (précédent, suivant)
        collectorNavigation.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
            if (hasResponded) return;  // Prevent multiple responses

            try {
                await interaction.deferUpdate();
                hasResponded = true; // Mark interaction as responded
                console.log('Interaction différée (navigation)', interaction.customId);

                if (interaction.customId === `prev1_${message.id}`) {
                    if (p0 - count >= 0) {
                        p0 -= count;
                        p1 -= count;
                        page--;
                        embed.setFooter({ text: `${page}/${Math.ceil(data.length / count)} ${client.footer}` })
                            .setDescription(data.slice(p0, p1).map((m) => `**<t:${m.ID.split("_")[2]}>** - **${m.ID.split("_")[3]}**`).join("\n") || "Aucune donnée");
                        await msg.edit({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });
                    }
                }

                if (interaction.customId === `prev2_${message.id}`) {
                    if (p1 < data.length) {
                        p0 += count;
                        p1 += count;
                        page++;
                        embed.setFooter({ text: `${page}/${Math.ceil(data.length / count)} ${client.footer}` })
                            .setDescription(data.slice(p0, p1).map((m) => `**<t:${m.ID.split("_")[2]}>** - **${m.ID.split("_")[3]}**`).join("\n") || "Aucune donnée");
                        await msg.edit({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erreur lors de la collecte de la navigation :', error);
            }
        });

        // Collecteur de suppression (corbeille)
        collectorDelete.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
            if (hasResponded) return;  // Prevent multiple responses

            try {
                await interaction.deferUpdate();
                hasResponded = true; // Mark interaction as responded
                console.log('Interaction différée (corbeille)', interaction.customId);

                if (interaction.customId === `poubelle_${message.id}`) {
                    if (interaction.user.id !== membre.id && interaction.user.id !== message.author.id) {
                        console.log('Tentative de suppression invalide');
                        await interaction.reply({
                            content: 'Seule la personne mentionnée peut supprimer ce message.',
                            ephemeral: true,
                        });
                        return;
                    } else {
                        await msg.delete();
                        console.log('Message supprimé par l\'utilisateur mentionné.');
                        await interaction.reply({
                            content: 'Le message a été supprimé.',
                            ephemeral: true,
                        });
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erreur lors de la collecte de suppression :', error);
            }
        });

        collectorNavigation.on('end', async () => {
            await msg.edit({ components: [new MessageActionRow().addComponents(btnDelete)] });
            console.log('Collecteur de navigation terminé.');
        });

        collectorDelete.on('end', async () => {
            console.log('Collecteur de suppression terminé.');
        });
    },
};

